# Incluir validado em um código VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho um código que importa dados de outras planilhas, mas queria que existisse um validador do tipo na hora de importar ele verificasse que existe um registro repetido que atualizasse. Por exemplo, importei uma planilha, mais de um tempo incluir mais uma informação ele iria ler que já possui os dados e com dado novo que inserir iria "sobressair" a informação já inserida.

```html
Sub Importar_Dados()

On Error GoTo Erro

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Guia As Object
Dim Planilha As Workbook
Dim EnderecoPlan As String
Dim Coluna As Double, Linha As Double, ColDestino As Double
Dim ColInicial As Double, ColFinal As Double, LinOrigem As Double

EnderecoPlan = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="file,*.xls*")

If EnderecoPlan <> Empty And EnderecoPlan <> "Falso" Then
    Set Planilha = Application.Workbooks.Open(EnderecoPlan)
    Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Set Guia = Planilha.Worksheets(1)

Windows(Planilha.Name).Visible = False

Coluna = 1
Linha = 1

Inicio:
Do
    Linha = Linha + 1
    
    If Guia.Cells(Linha, Coluna).Value <> Empty Then
        LinOrigem = Linha
        ColInicial = Coluna
        Do
        Coluna = Coluna + 1
        Loop Until Guia.Cells(Linha, Coluna).Value = Empty
        
        ColFinal = Coluna - 1
        Exit Do
    End If
    
    If Coluna = 100 Then
        Msgbox "Não encontrado cabeçalho!", vbExclamation, "IMPORTAR"
    Exit Sub
    End If

Loop Until Linha = 10

If LinOrigem = Empty Then
    Coluna = Coluna + 1
    Linha = 1
    GoTo Inicio:
End If

Coluna = ColInicial
ColDestino = 1
Linha = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Planilha2.Range("A:A")) + 2

With Planilha2

    Do
    LinOrigem = LinOrigem + 1
    
    For Coluna = ColInicial To ColFinal
        .Cells(Linha, ColDestino).Value = Guia.Cells(LinOrigem, Coluna).Value
        ColDestino = ColDestino + 1
        
    Next Coluna
    
    ColDestino = 1
    Linha = Linha + 1

Loop Until Guia.Cells(LinOrigem, ColInicial).Value = Empty
End With

Windows(Planilha.Name).Visible = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Windows(Planilha.Name).Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Set Planilha = Nothing
Set Guia = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
Erro:
Msgbox "Erro!", vbCritical, "IMPORTAR"

End Sub
```

Comment: Não é necessário VBA para isso. É só você selecionar a coluna na qual quer aplicar essa conferência e, na faixa de opções, menu `Página Inicial`, agrupamento `Estilo`, clicar no botão `Formatação Condicional` > `Realçar regras das células` > `Valores duplicados` e, na caixa de diálogo que vai aparecer, chamada `Valores Duplicados`, você escolhe se quer destacar os duplicados ou os exclusivos, escolhe um formato do destaque ao lado e clica em `ok`. Daí, sempre que entrarem valores repetidos nessa coluna, a formatação condicional será aplicada automaticamente.

Comment: Oi! Conheço desse recurso no excel mas eu queria aplicar direto no código.

Comment: Tudo bem, mais tarde eu posto uma resposta explicando. Só um detalhe: a formatação condicional é como um "toggle": você liga e desliga ela. Você não precisa refazer essa operação toda vez. Se a planilha for a mesma, e você tiver ativado a formatação condicional na forma do meu comentário anterior, sempre que seu código aportar mais dados nela, a formatação condicional já estará ligada e vai acusar duplicatas nos novos dados também, sem precisar ser ligada de novo.